# Observer is always one state late

Tags: ember.js

I have the following issue: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/goqera/13/ where I print out the selected option ids. The ids are updated in an observer that gets triggered when the checked property changes.

When you try it, you will see that the printed ids are always from the previous state, instead of the current state. The active count is correct, the active ids are one state behind...

```
// this computed property is correct and reflects the current checked options state
checkedOptions: Ember.computed.filterBy('model', 'checked', true),

// this observer is always one state behind
observeCheckedListOptions: function() {    
    this.set('checkedOptionIds', this.get('checkedOptions').mapBy('id'));
}.observes('model.@each.checked').on('init')
```

I believe something in the observer is wrong, because the computed property `checkedOptions` is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no [run-loop](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/run-loop/) expert but I *think* this is happening because you're observing a different property to the one you're getting. So, to describe the behaviour with your current code:

1. A box is checked, this is a change to `model.@each.checked` so any dependant computed properties need to be updated and any observers need to be run. This work is added to a queue using the run-loop, there are separate queues for computed property updates and observers.
2. First, the observer queue is run - this runs your observer and when you do `this.get('checkedOptions')` you get the value pre-update (because that work happens in a queue of lower priority)
3. The computed property queue is run, which doesn't help you at all.

So, with this knowledge you have a few options for a fix. The answer from undeletable is fine, if you only use computed properties then you won't get caught out by different queues. Another alternative would be to observe the property you get, this way your observer will only fire after the property has been updated:

```
observeCheckedListOptions: function() {    
    this.set('checkedOptionIds', this.get('checkedOptions').mapBy('id'));
}.observes('checkedOptions.@each').on('init')
```

However, my favourite solution has to be using another computed property macro:

```
checkedOptionIds: Ember.computed.mapBy('checkedOptions', 'id')
```

There is a catch with this though, when done this way it's an actual array and (annoyingly) handlebars refuses to render it (I still don't know why) so you would need to do this as well in the template:

```
{{#each id in checkedOptionIds }}
    {{id}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank for bringing up the runloop. That was indeed the cause of the state behind problem. I now observe the property I am using in the observer, which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say exactly what is the reason, but in your case I don't see why is it necessary to use observer which just sets a single property instead of making it computed one (see [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/lajuwalacu/1/edit)):

```
checkedOptionIds: function() {    
  return this.get('checkedOptions').mapBy('id');
}.property('checkedOptions.@each.checked')
```

Comment: Well I need an observer because I want to reflect the ids in a Query Parameter.

Comment: I could also deal with observer changing its parameter from `model.@each.checked` to `checkedOptions.@each.checked`